# PHP file_put_contents returning 'Permission Denied' (Due to SELinux setting)

Tags: php, apache, rhel, selinux

I know this is a common issue but I haven't been able to single out the problem for my specific use case, so bear with me.

I have a simple PHP script `send_id` which simply sends an ID number and saves it to a TXT file on my RHEL server running Apache 2.4.6 with PHP 5.4.

The error message: `Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/id.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/send_id.php on line 6
'1' written to server`

The PHP script itself:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$stringData = "$id";
$file = file_put_contents('/var/www/html/id.txt', $stringData.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND |LOCK_EX);
echo "'$stringData' written to server";
?>
```

chmodding to 777 didn't do anything. Additionally, I checked to see ownership rights and noticed that the id.txt file is owned by the root user at both user/group level, and PHP is being run at root level.

Anyone have any suggestions? If its any help, this seems to have happened after a `yum update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by simply running `chcon -Rt httpd_sys_content_rw_t` on the directory where my troubled PHP script lived in.

> The `chcon` command changes the SELinux context for files. However, changes made with the `chcon` command are not persistent across file-system relabels, or the execution of the `restorecon` command.

`-Rt` are to change the type of the directory and its contents, `httpd_sys_content_rw_t` is to give apache write access

source: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files

Additional note

```
ls -alZ *
```

The -Z switch will work with most utilities to show SELinux security contexts

Comment: Yes, +1 for not just disabling SELinux!

Comment: well... while that will work, can't reccomend that..  Please see my answer

Comment: Aaaaand what does that do exactly?

Comment: I suggested an edit based on the RHEL SELinux User guide to explain the `chcon` command - see 4.7.1 here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the owner of the folder and the file to (`chown`) to "www-data" or to "www-data:www-data" and see if it changes anything...

Comment: Nope, unfortunately did not do anything

Answer (score -1):

Use a relative file path from,  Apache's "DOCUMENT ROOT" to reference files in PHP.  It's Apache's permissions that matter, and for security reasons it is coded to inhibit access to files outside of DOCUMENT_ROOT.. (yes even though your path leads within it, Apache is blocked as soon as it sees the path starts with "/VAR"  ..

Assuming this PHP script is in the same directory as id.txt file , just use

```
$file = file_put_contents('./id.txt', $str...
```

Or if the txt file was in a sub-directory

```
file_put_contents('./sub-dir/id.txt', $str...
```

Not only is it secure, it's a lot shorter to type too.

Comment: "Apache is blocked as soon as it sees the path starts with /VAR" That's a load of nonsense.

Comment: It was `./id.txt` at first but that still resulted in the problem. My solution below has fixed the problem though